# My application crashes on Android 7.0

Tags: java, android

I developed an Android app and it was working perfectly on Android 6.0.
After I updated to the new Android 7.0 now the app crashes. The stack trace of `logcat` is :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.plexis.holford, PID: 28306 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/com.plexis.holford-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes10.dex)
                       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
                       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
                       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
                       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
                       at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                       at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                       at com.plexis.holford.MainActivity.displayFirebaseRegId(MainActivity.java:216)
                       at com.plexis.holford.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:201)
                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6910)
                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2746)
                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6531)
                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
```

I have disabled Instant run, and re-build the app, but no success.

**EDIT**
build.gradle contents

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.plexis.holford"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'

    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**EDIT-2**
The app main activity is launching with no error when I click sign-in the app crashes.
I stopped the code that is registering to FireBase, and now the app works.
I will check which statement is throwing the error and posted here.

**Edit-3**
My mobile is running Android 7.0 and the app is working good, after removing the firebase code, but it is crashing on another mobile with same android version1.
Any ideas?

Comment: please add your gradle file content

Comment: @OğuzhanDöngül please check now

Comment: Do you try refresh gradle, clean then re-build project? I went through this error before. Clean - rebuild worked for me.

Comment: @nhoxbypass yes i tried all of these

Comment: It's probably due to the older version of firebase. Use 11.4.2 instead of 9.0.0

Comment: reinstall the app